# Listener for check boxes in android

Tags: android

I have a layout with 10 check boxes. All check boxes are added through code. Now I was wondering if there's any listener available for the layout to check how many check boxes are selected. For instance: when I select 4 check boxes, I want to know how many and which check boxes were selected.

Comment: what is the problem? you know the id of CHB, then check for each if that is checked or not..

Comment: @edi233: Home this link may help you http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html

Comment: Why to have 10 separate `checkboxes`  use the concept of `ListView` with multi choice .

Comment: I have a problem because i wat to block select for checkboxs when 4 of all checkboxes are selected. I wat to implement system when I select 4 checkboxes I block select for others, after unselect one of this 4 I can select other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692494/android-checkbox-ischecked-is-always-returning-a-false-condition):

```
ckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      if (ckBox.isChecked()) {
        mDisplayHelp = true;
      } else {
        mDisplayHelp = false;
      }
```

> ```
>       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
>       editor.putBoolean("checkboxPref", mDisplayHelp);
>
>       // Don't forget to commit your edits!!!
>       editor.commit();
>       // Optional part
> ```

```
    }
});
```

Or you can just check each one of them like that:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    // Some wild things happen here
} else {
    // Okay ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add checkbox like `CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText("Dynamic Checkbox " + i);
            cb.setId(i+10);
            yourlayout.addView(cb);` you have to jst set their listener by calling setOnClickListerner(this); here. It will solve your issue.